# Yarn "add webpack" removes other packages?

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg

I'm going quietly mad here. My package need webpack and ts-loader to build.

I do `yarn add webpack --dev` and then webpack is in my `node_modules` folder. I now do `yarn add ts-loader --dev`  and ts-loader is there, but webpack is gone (although still shows in package.json)!

If I now add webpack again, ts-loader disappears... What's going on?

Using the `--verbose` flag, I can see that webpack is removing ts-loader as an 'extraneous package' and vice-versa.

I guess yarn has got itself horribly confused. How do I clear all it's local state and just get it to cleanly pull down the packages listed in package.json?

Comment: delete node_modules and just run `yarn`?  it seems to install both fine for me. my entire package.json is `{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  }
}`

Comment: edited in my package.json (dev)

Comment: Something weird is going on for me. I found that is i did `yarn add webpack ts-loader --dev` I'd get both, but if I then did `yarn upgrade` one would disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that by omitting the `--dev` flag when adding, the problem disappeared.

Reading the docs and code it appears that if the environment var `NODE_ENV` = `production` then Yarn will install the package and its requirements as a devDependency, but remove all other devDependency packages.

Here's a Github issue proposing a fix for this. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4095